# Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `model`. x object '.x' not found i Input `model` is `map(...)` in R tidyverse/dplyr? Ranger model

Tags: r, machine-learning, tidyverse, purrr, tibble

I am currently attempting to create a model using the ranger package.

I am pre-processing the data by creating cross-validated folds and then extracting the training and test data frames into their own list columns.

Here is the code below going from creating my training and test dataset to modeling and attempting to iterate my model on my cross-validated tibbles. [I am following basically following the steps here but with my own data and same data sctructure](https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/machine-learning-in-the-tidyverse/build-tune-evaluate-regression-models?ex=8)

```
Splitting Up the Data 
data_split <-  initial_split(historical_df, prop = .80)

#Creating Training Dataset
training_data <- training(data_split)


#Creating Testing Dataset
testing_data <- testing(data_split)


#Counting Rows in the Training Dataset
nrow(training_data)

#Counting Rows in the Testing Dataset
nrow(testing_data)

#Creating cross validated data frames 
cv_data_split <-  vfold_cv(training_data, v = 5)
cv_data_split

#Extract Training and Testing Data Franes into their Own List Columns
cv_data <- cv_data_split %>% 
  mutate(train = map(splits, ~training(.x)), 
         validate = map(splits, ~testing(.x)))


#Creating Ranger/Random Forest Model with Cross Validated Data & Following tidy ML Steps Usins Tibbles 
cv_model_rf <- cv_data %>% 
  mutate(model = map(train, ranger(formula = E2E_BUS_DAYS~ ORD_DOW + SG_LOC + RDC_NBR + STR_NBR + MKT_NBR + RGN_NBR + DIST,
                                              data = .x, seed = 42, 
                                   num.trees = 100 ,
                                   mtry = 3,
                                   quantreg = TRUE,
                                   min.node.size = 30,
                                       importance = 'permutation')))
#ERROR
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `model`.
x object '.x' not found
i Input `model` is `map(...)`
```

I am unsure as to what the issue is with mutate is and .x was created in the cv_data variable. The cv_data object looks as such

[image]

Here is the object cv_data_split

[image]

Here is a glimpse and head view of my data
[image]

[image]

Comment: Try adding `~` i.e `map(train, ~ranger(formula .....`